# how to name SR-IOV Virtual Functions

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ethernet, interface, sr-iov

When an SR-IOV Virtual Function (VF) is created, the Linux kernel names it ethX, with X being the lowest available index among Ethernet interfaces.

Is there a way to control such naming?

For instance, I'd like a rule saying that all VFs should be in a given form (e.g. ethvf[0-9]*) or even just making sure that the numerical part of the name will be taken from a given range (e.g. eth100-eth200).

The current behaviour is undesirable when some other physical interface, previously called ethX by the kernel, is handled by a DPDK driver and no more by the kernel driver. If at this point I create a VF from a different interface, this VF will take the lowest available index, which happens to be X!

If ever I decide to unbind the interface in DPDK mode and give it back to the kernel, it won't find its original name 'ethX' available any more and will take another index.

(I'm running Debian 8.2 with the Linux kernel 4.6.1)

Comment: Did you turn off consistent network device naming? What you have described is not default or expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's turned off. Is it possible to control the naming with the old scheme eth[0-9]+ ?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You'll need consistent network device naming for this. In fact, this is one of the problems that consistent network device naming was intended to solve.